# A problem with partitions of integers

Tags: combinatorics

Given a partition $\nu$ of $k$ with $n-k$ joined( in the correct position) and define $\mu$ to be $\nu$ with $n-k+1$ adjoined. This yields the desired bijection, so we get the answer $p(0)+\ldots+p(n)$.

Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Generating functions, for instance. Given a partition $\lambda$ of $n$, the number of partitions of $n+1$ which can be derived from $\lambda$ by adding a square at the end of some row is given by how many different row lengths appear in $\lambda$. Let us consider the generating function for partitions:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}p(n) x^n = (1+x+x^2+\ldots)(1+x^2+x^4+\ldots)(1+x^3+x^6+\ldots)\cdots =\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-x^k} $$
and let us add a tag variable $y$:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}p(n,y)x^n = \prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+yx^k+yx^{2k}+\ldots\right) = \prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1+(y-1)x^k}{1-x^k}$$
By this way, the coefficient of $y^h x^n$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with exactly $h$ distinct parts, and what we want is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\frac{d}{dy}\text{RHS}$ evaluated at $y=1$. Since $\frac{df}{dy}=f\cdot\frac{d}{dy}\log f$, the answer is given by the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1} x^k \prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-x^k} = \frac{x}{1-x}\sum_{n\geq 0}p(n)x^n $$
which is $p(0)+p(1)+\ldots+p(n-1)$.